# Convert monad to monadparallel

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, functional-programming, monads

I want to convert the `liftM2` function in `Control.Monad` to `liftM2` function in `Control.Monad.Parallel`. I tried just change the import package from `Control.Monad` to `Control.Monad.Parallel`, then GHC output the error like "no instance for `MonadParallel`".

Could you help me or give some sort of hint on how to convert the monad to `MonadParallel` type?

A sample code illustrates as below:

```
MoPar.liftM2 (,) (randNum (0, maxX) gen) (randNum (0, maxY) gen) >>= do
        visit gen visited rWalls bWalls
    MoPar.liftM2 Maze (freeze rWalls) (freeze bWalls)
```

`MoPar` means `Monad.Parallel` package, which occurs errors. If I change it to `Mon` which is `Control.Monad` and will pass the compile. Do I miss something on the around `liftM2` function in source code?

Comment: Well, as it says, your monad is not an instance of `MonadParallel`. Either define that instance yourself, or switch to a monad that has such an instance.

Comment: Can you post the error?  What Monad are you trying to use?

Comment: To leftaroundabout, could you please tell me some kind of definition of a MonadParallel instance?